# Getting this error when trying to create an user in IDM ORA-01653: unable to extend table WAVESET.USERATTR by 512 in tablespace WAVESET_DATA

Tags: oracle

Please let me know what to do here to get the user created in IDM where as i deleted some old files in the server to make some space available

Comment: creating a user has nothing to do with deleting "old files".  what version of oracle, what files did you delete?

Comment: Here is the total error i am getting when i am trying to create a new user in the IDM
Error
The request to create an account did not complete fully due to the following errors:
ORA-01653: unable to extend table WAVESET.USERATTR by 512 in tablespace WAVESET_DATA

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129376/ora-01653-unable-to-extend-table-by-in-tablespace-ora-06512/27129693#27129693

Comment: I am not sure of the version but i deleted some old log files in the JBOSS server so can you please suggest what can i do to create an user without getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your tablespace WAVESET_DATA is full and you do not have auto extend set on the datafiles.

Either add a new datafile or increase the size of the existing ones.

In a nutshell you are out of space for Oracle but not necessarily out of disk space. Be extremely careful in deleting old files.  Anything in the app or oracle folder should be left alone until you know what it is.