# how to use cursor.executemany with json data for oracle inserts

Tags: python, json, oracle

Inserting the rows into oracle table with cursor execute takes a lot of time in my python script. Turned auto-commit to false but still the same. Tried executemany with no luck, as it throws error.  Below is my code:

```
insert_statement='INSERT INTO mytable
VALUES (:1,:2)
'
r = requests.get(url,cert=(auth_certificate,priv_key),verify=root_cert, timeout=3600, stream=True)

data=json.loads(r.text)

for item in data:
    try:
        id=(item.Get('data').get("test").get("id"))
    except Attribute Error:
        id=''
    try:
        name=(item.Get('data').get("name"))
    except Attribute Error:
        name=''
    rows=(id,name)
    cursor.Executemany(insert_statement,rows)
    connection_target.commit()
```

this throws error: TypeError: parameters should be a list of sequences/dictionaries or an integer specifying the number of times to execute the statement

could you please advise how to correctly use executemany with json data ?

Here the sample json data :

```
json_data=[{
  "publishTime" : "2021-05-29T12:52:15.129Z",
  "data" : {
    "identifier" : {
      "domain" : "AB",
      "id" : "1771374",
      "version" : "58593668"
    },
    "Accounts" : [
      {
        "effectiveEndDate" : "3000-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "Name" : "w (S)",
        "effectiveStartDate" : "2016-09-16T04:21:33Z",
        "sAccount" : "SGLDPB_A"
      }
    ]
  }
}]
```

Comment: Your insert statement has 20 columns, but your `rows=(id,name)` only has 2. How many are you trying to insert? Could you edit your question to add some details about your table and JSON structures?

Comment: sorry , my bad i copied a wrong insert statement. Only 2 rows for now, but will have many later. i have added the same json data input. Just want to know the correct way of using executemany

Comment: You are passing ONE row to `executemany`.  That's not how it works.  Your `for` loop should build up a list, where each element is a row you want to insert.  Then, after the loop has ended, you call `executemany` and pass your list of rows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to gather up a list of rows, and then pass that list to `executemany` after the loop is complete.  And watch your capitalization.  Plus, the names in your code do not match the names in your sample JSON.

Note that I've modified this to do 1,000 rows at a time.

```
insert_statement='INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (:1,:2)'
r = requests.get(url,cert=(auth_certificate,priv_key),verify=root_cert, timeout=3600, stream=True)

data=json.loads(r.text)

myrows = []
for item in data:
    try:
        id=item['data']["identifier"]["id"]
    except AttributeError:
        id=''
    try:
        name=item['Accounts'][0]['Name']
    except AttributeError:
        name=''
    myrows.append( (id, name) )
    if len(myrows) >= 1000:
        cursor.executemany(insert_statement,myrows)
        myrows = []

cursor.executemany(insert_statement,myrows)
connection_target.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. Sorry new to python and learning. The above atleast does not give me any error. It runs but seems to be stuck on executemany step . There are no issues with table as i could insert data separately into it. Do you have any advise?

Comment: How many rows are you adding?  I believe there are better ways to do bulk insertion into an Oracle DB.

Comment: there are about 100k rows. what would be the efficient way to perform the bulk insertion?

Comment: I was wrong, `executemany` is the preferred method.  It makes one network round-trip.  Unless your network is from 1995, I would expect that to take less than 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  After 30 mins it errors out with "cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01653: unable to extend table mytable by 8192 in tablespace DATA.  Could the prolonged execution time be because of tablespace?

Comment: That's too Oracle-specific for me.  There seems to be something about it here, but I'm not smart enough to interpret it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129376/ora-01653-unable-to-extend-table-by-in-tablespace-ora-06512

Comment: You MIGHT try breaking this up into smaller chunks, like doing 1000 rows at a time.  I'll show how.

Comment: thanks . I will take a look. I really appreciate your prompt help so far. cheers

Comment: I  troubleshooted the script run from database , i have 95k rows in the json file ,but the executemany keeps ingesting duplicate rows into table in loop. this may be the reason why tablespace was running out.  The execute just worked fine, not sure if i missed anything in the code ?

Comment: You shouldn't get duplicates unless there are duplicates in your JSON data.  My (revised) loop ingests 1,000 rows, then clears the rowset, then ingests another 1,000 rows.